# How to send local stream to backend using flutter_webrtc?

Tags: flutter, flutter-webrtc

I am creating some kind of streaming app on mobile phones. I am launching front camera and displaying it on phone. Main purpose is to send that footage to my backend and then display it on website.
How I am supposed to do this? I need some server to do it?

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc

```
final RTCVideoRenderer _localRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer()
```

```
_localRenderer.initialize();
```

```
var stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({'video': true, 'audio': true});
    setState(() {
      _localRenderer.srcObject = stream;
    });
```